# Login help page has misleading information

Tags: feature-request, bug, login

I just wanted to login on chat.stackexchange.com, but couldn't. When I went to the [help page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help), the checks failed on test 5. It claimed:

> Your browser either does not support localStorage, or it is disabled for stackauth.com. Either upgrade your browser, or enable localStorage.

In fact, the problem was that Chrome blocks the third-party cookie for stackauth.com by default (it's in Dutch, but it just shows the "Blocked" cookies for the current page):

[image]

After allowing this cookie, the login works just fine. So IMHO it would really help to add some sort of hint in the test 5 error text that blocking cookies from stackauth.com might also cause the login failure and allowing that cookie could fix it.

Comment: Hmm... on my copy of Chrome, the neither `stackauth.com` or `cdn.sstatic.net` have their cookies blocked by default. Are you running any plugins that could be messing with setting cookies?

Comment: No, but I do have third-party cookies disabled. I thought that was by default, but now I'm starting to doubt. Either way, my main point is that the error message could probably be extended/improved to cover the fact that cookies might be the problem, rather than localStorage.